# I am missing a return statement

Tags: java

I am building a DAO Factory for my project

this is the class:

```
package Dao;

import Interfaces.IDAOProject;
import datapackage.DbObject;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import type.programma.Oefening;


public class DAOProject extends DbObject implements IDAOProject {

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Oefening> load(Oefening o) {

       try{
    String sql = "LOAD FROM Oefeningen set Code = " + o.getCode() + " WHERE Code = " + o.getCode();
    OpenConnection();
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());}


    }
}
```

now he gives an error @ `public class DAOProject extends DbObject implements IDAOProject {`
that he is missing a return statement  how can i fix this?

Comment: the function is specified to return something (`ArrayList<Oefening>`), so return it - and if you don't know what this means, read a good book first!

Comment: Either declare your method as "public void" OR return an ArrayList<Oefening>

Comment: need to return `ArrayList<Oefening>` as per your method signature else change signature to void

Comment: i have add this to my code: return load(o);

Answer (score 2):

You have declared your method as

`public ArrayList<Oefening> load(Oefening o)`

Shouldn't you be returning the `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 0):

Your load(...) method should always return some ArrayList, or throw an exception. In your code you have a try-catch statement, wich is not returning anything. One solution would be to rethrow the same exception, if you do not know how to handle it better at this point, like so:

```
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());}
    throw e;
}
```